# CORS Error when invoking 'GET' from external API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, get, cors, xmlhttprequest

I have a normal HTML/JavaScript application where I am trying to request a GET from the API's URL. When I ran the program, it returned this error:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'URL' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Here is my function:

```
 function displayData(){
    searchData = "";
    const data = JSON.stringify(false);
        
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "url", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('AccessKey', "...");
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Token', "..."); 
  xhr.withCredentials = true; 


  // Set up a callback function to handle the response
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        // Request was successful, handle the response here
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log('Response:', response);
      } else {
        // Request failed, handle errors here
        console.error('Error:', xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
      }
    }
  };

  // Send the HTTP request
  xhr.send();
  }
```

I went to do some research and added things like `xhr.withCredentials = true;` but it doesn't work. Many solutions require me to edit the server settings to allow CORS requests, but I don't own the server and probably can't work around it. I also tried downloading the Allow CORS extension on Chrome and enabling it, but the error still persists.

How can I edit my code so that the CORS issue can be solved? I would appreciate any help or guidance from the community. Thank you!

Comment: CORS is a server side control, i.e. the server decides if it will grant access. The fact that `from origin 'null'` however, suggests your web page is being served over `file:///` rather than a http server, therefore, there is absolutely nothing you can do to fix your problem, unless you start using a http server

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, thank you for your reply. Would hosting it on localhost do the trick?

Comment: that's step 1 for CORS - but if the external API doesn't allow CORS, then the next step is to use the server on localhost to proxy the request for the client

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX, thank you for your reply. May I know how do you do that? I'm new to proxy servers so some guidance or resources would be good! Thank you

Comment: sorry, proxy in the sense that you use your server to *proxy* the request on behalf of your client (browser)

Comment: Ahh I got it. I hosted a proxy server using Express then called the API using the proxy server. After that, used  GET request to the proxy server from my HTML page to get the data out. Thanks for the help!